# how to get request value in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I can read from web.config through using this script

```
<li><a href="mailto:<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMAIL"] %>">
```

How can I read from request form?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your question/requirement?

Comment: `<%=`?  In 2020? I thought people stopped using that for asp.net back in 2005.

Comment: Also, the above isn't just snark (okay, it's mostly snark)... but we do really need to know exactly what kind of project this: very old web site/application vs not quite as old web forms vs MVC vs Core. All of those can have a slightly different answer to this question.